# Selenium unable to invoke Edge browser version 17763

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-ide, selenium-rc

I am trying to automate test cases using perl selenium with edge browser. I am using win10 build 1809 and edge version is 18.17763. I have used various selenium server version from 3.13,3,14, 3.3,3.4
None of them has solved my problem.

Below is the error i get :

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:11575/

Listening on http://[::1]:11575/

Invalid capabilities

07:08:20.646 WARN - Exception thrown

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
```

below is my code invocation code:
[Code snippet image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2TQg.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers. Also, please edit your question to include the code (rather than post as a screenshot).  Perl selenium?  Wonders never cease :)

Comment: Perhaps the webdriver version is not compatible with your Windows and Edge browser version, please check [this article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/), make sure you are installing the correct version of Microsoft WebDriver, then, refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver) and [this blog](https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver) to use it.

Comment: Ofcourse i have matched both versions. none works.